# (H.W) Munkres Topology: Proof of Extreme value theorem?

Tags: general-topology

The Author says:
If $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous function where $X$ is compact and $Y$ has ordered topology, then the image $A = f(X)$ is also compact. Now we assume $A$ has no largest element (or minimum). **Then the collection of $\{(-\infty,a)\mid a \in A\}$ form an open covering of A**. I didn't understand why the statement in bold is true. Because $(-\infty,a)$ is open in $A$, it will not contain '$a$' and hence some '$a$' will be left out, so how does it cover $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $A$. Then since $A$ has no largest element, there exists some $a\in A$ with $a>x$, so $x\in (-\infty,a)$. Thus every element of $A$ is in one of these open intervals, so we have an open cover.

Comment: Since a is also in A, we end up with infinitely many open cover which contradicts the compactness- is this conclusion right in concluding the proof.

Comment: Essentially yes. You can contradict compactness because any finite number of sets of the form $(-\infty,a)$ with $a\in A$ will not contain the largest such $a$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in A$ and $a$ is maximal and the set $A$ is not directed by relation $\leq$ then it is possible that $a$ not belongs to any $(\leftarrow , b)$ for any $b\in A.$ But if $A$ is directed then you can take any uncomparable with $a$ element $c\in A$ and since $A$ is directed then there exists $d\in A$ such that $a\leq d $ and $c\leq d$ hence $a\in (\leftarrow , d).$